# SAP Hybris can't create custom banner component

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I want to create custom banner component, extended from `SimpleBannerComponent`. But after I created it, it fails to create in Backoffice, see below.

1) I added this item to my `*-items.xml` file.

```
<itemtype code="PromotionBannerCMSComponent" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="SimpleBannerComponent"
          jaloclass="my.package.core.jalo.components.PromotionBannerCMSComponent">
    <description>Promotion banner component</description>
    <deployment table="PromotionBanners" typecode="15301"/>
    <attributes>
        <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String">
            <persistence type="property"/>
            <modifiers/>
            <description>Banner name (not unique)</description>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="title" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Title</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true"/>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="position" type="SimpleBannerPositionEnum">
            <description>Banner position</description>
            <modifiers optional="true" initial="true"/>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="altText" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Banner alt text</description>
            <modifiers optional="true" initial="true"/>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="titleSecondary" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Title secondary</description>
            <persistence type="property" />
            <modifiers />
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="urlLoc" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Banner url</description>
            <persistence type="property" />
            <modifiers />
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

2) I did `ant clean all`, restarted server, I've run `HAC -> Update` with my custom extension checked and with `Update running system` also checked. Then I did a server restart again.

3) I wanted to create the component in the Backoffice `WCMS->Components->Add`, but it fails with error - I've turned on the `flexible.search.exception.show.query.details` to see it:

```
 [ConfigurableFlowController] Object  could not be saved
com.hybris.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.object.exceptions.ObjectSavingException: Object  could not be saved
```

and

```
Caused by: de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException: [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.UniqueAttributesInterceptor@716c1b71]: unexpected validator error: SQL search error - Unknown column 'item_t0.p_catalogversion' in 'where clause' query = 'SELECT  item_t0.PK  FROM cmscomponent item_t0 WHERE
.
.
```

Now I can't create even the basic SimpleBannerComponent, neither the other components. Is there something wrong with the update? 
I'm using Hybris 1811.18.

Comment: Did you try `ant updatesystem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had an old deployment table which collided with this component, somehow it didn't show an error during `ant clean all`.

So I run in HAC `delete from ydeployments where typecode=XX;` (XX is typecode found in HAC) and started over with almost the same deployment, except I removed jaloclass and deployment table description:

```
<itemtype code="PromotionBannerCMSComponent" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="SimpleBannerComponent">
    <description>Promotion banner component</description>
    <attributes>
        <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String">
            <persistence type="property"/>
            <modifiers/>
            <description>Banner name (not unique)</description>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="title" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Title</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true"/>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="position" type="SimpleBannerPositionEnum">
            <description>Banner position</description>
            <modifiers optional="true" initial="true"/>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="altText" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Banner alt text</description>
            <modifiers optional="true" initial="true"/>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="titleSecondary" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Title secondary</description>
            <persistence type="property" />
            <modifiers />
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="urlLoc" type="localized:java.lang.String">
            <description>Banner url</description>
            <persistence type="property" />
            <modifiers />
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem that I am able to see is that the deployment table should be deleted since the best practice is to provide one only when extending the **GenericItem**(when you do not specify a parent this type will be automatically set). So your definition should look like this:

```
<itemtype code="PromotionBannerCMSComponent" autocreate="true" generate="true" extends="SimpleBannerComponent"
      jaloclass="my.package.core.jalo.components.PromotionBannerCMSComponent">
<description>Promotion banner component</description>
<attributes>
    <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String">
        <persistence type="property"/>
        <modifiers/>
        <description>Banner name (not unique)</description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute qualifier="title" type="localized:java.lang.String">
        <description>Title</description>
        <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true"/>
        <persistence type="property"/>
    </attribute>
    <attribute qualifier="position" type="SimpleBannerPositionEnum">
        <description>Banner position</description>
        <modifiers optional="true" initial="true"/>
        <persistence type="property"/>
    </attribute>
    <attribute qualifier="altText" type="localized:java.lang.String">
        <description>Banner alt text</description>
        <modifiers optional="true" initial="true"/>
        <persistence type="property"/>
    </attribute>
    <attribute qualifier="titleSecondary" type="localized:java.lang.String">
        <description>Title secondary</description>
        <persistence type="property" />
        <modifiers />
    </attribute>
    <attribute qualifier="urlLoc" type="localized:java.lang.String">
        <description>Banner url</description>
        <persistence type="property" />
        <modifiers />
    </attribute>
</attributes>
```

Try to initialize the system in order to test this in order to delete the old type and its associated table from the database.

Comment: `One of the problem that I am able to see is that the deployment table should be deleted ` - This is not the root cause of the problem. It is just that putting an additional deployment table, in this case, will require the FS query to create some more joins.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with 1905.13, and it's working fine. (I needed to adjust the package name and add the SimpleBannerPositionEnum definition) I simply did "ant all" in command-line and "Update running system" during Platform Update (without any extension checked). I'm able to create an instance of PromotionBannerCMSComponent in backoffice.

Have you tried initializing and see if it works on your side? Otherwise, you may need to share more about the error / stacktrace.